# Show that $f_n(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff $n$ is prime

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone please take a look at this and let me know what you think. Thanks in advance!

Given $n\geq2$, since $1 \in \mathbb{Q}$ is a root of $x^n-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, the factor theorem tells us that $(x-1)$ divides $x^n-1$.

If $f_n(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is the quotient, then:

$$f_n(x)=(x^n-1)/(x-1)=x^{n-1} +x^{n-2}+\dots+x+1$$

Show that $f_n(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff n is prime. (Hint: if n=p is prime and $y=x-1$, then $f_p(x)=f_p((y+1)^p-1)/y$. Simplify and use Eisenstein's criterion.)

If $f_n(x)$ is irreducible $\in \mathbb{Q}$[x], n is prime. Assume $f_n(x)$ is reducible $\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and P does not divide $a_n$.

Simplifying $f_p(x)=[a_n]*y^{n-1}+[a_{n-1}]*y^{n-2}+\dots+[a_1]*y \in \mathbb{Z_p}$

If $f_p(x)$ is reducible, then $f_p(x)=g_p(x)*h_p(x)$ where,

$g_p(x)=[b_1]*y+\dots+[b_k]*y^{k-1}, h_p(x)=[c_1]*y+\dots+[c_m]*y^{m-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$

The function from $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z_p}$that sends $d\mapsto[d]$ is a ring homomorphism hence,

$$a_i=[b_o][c_i]+[b_1][c_{i-1}]+\dots+[b_i][c_0]$$

so, $[a_n]*y^{n-1}+[a_{n-1}]*y{n-2}+\dots+[a_1]*y=([b_1]*y+\dots+[b_n]*y^{n-1})([c_1]*y+\dots+[c_m]*y^{m-1}$)

Hence, $f_n(x)$ is reducible unless one of the polynomials is a constant polynomial. But as P does not divide $a_n$ the degree of $f_n(x)=g_n()x)*h_n(x)$ is $n=k+m$. This is a contradiction. $\therefore f_n$ is irreducible if $n=p$.

If n is prime, $f_n(x)$ is irreducible.

$f_p(x)=a_n*y^{p-1}+a_{n-1}*y^{p-2}+\dots+a_1*y+a_0$, and p does not divide $a_n=1$ and $p^2$ does not divide $a_0$

$\therefore$ if n is prime, $f_n(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: Skimming through the proof, you have written the following things: 1) The goal is to prove $A\Leftrightarrow B$; 2) Let's prove $A\Rightarrow B$; 3) Assume $\neg A$ (as if you wanted to prove $\neg A\Rightarrow \neg B$; 4) *stuff...*; 5) "We've successfully proved $B\Rightarrow A$", consistently with [3] but not with [2]; 6) Let's prove $B\Rightarrow A$ again; 7) *other stuff...*; 8) "We've proved $B\Rightarrow A$".

Comment: Proof. If $f(x)$ is reducible, then by Theorem 11.4, there exist nonconstant polynomials $g(x) = b_0 +···+b_l*x^l $ and $ h(x) = c_0 +···+c_m*x^m \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, with $b_l \neq 0 \neq c_m$
and $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$. Now, p divides $a_0 = b_0*c_0,$ but $p^2$ does not.

This is from Eisenstein's criterion. Can someone tell me how we know the last sentence is true.